# Bulk friend Request insertion based on array input in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array,

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [did] => 12 [uid] => 21 )
    [1] => Array ( [did] => 10 [uid] => 12 )
    [2] => Array ( [did] => 9 [uid] => 11 )
    [3] => Array ( [did] => 10 [uid] => 11 )
    [4] => Array ( [did] => 12 [uid] => 11 ) 
)
```

where I want all the uids who have the same `did` value to be connected with each other. For example- for `did=12, uids- 21 & 11` should be connected with each other. I am struggling to figure out how to do this in PHP and MySQL? Please note that array gets generated dynamically using query and can have many rows.

Comment: Use nested for loop and add did to new array. For every loop check if current did is already exists in that array and push uids.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi can you plz share the code for it? it will help a lot. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get all `uids` for every `did`?

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi Yes all the uids for same did. for example for did 12, uid 21 and 11 should be connected. for did 10, uid 11 & 12 should be connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over the array and use the `did` as the key. If the key already exists, add to the array, else create a new entry using the key:

```
$items = [
    ["did" => 12, "uuid" => 21],
    ["did" => 10, "uuid" => 12],
    ["did" => 9, "uuid" => 11],
    ["did" => 10, "uuid" => 11],
    ["did" => 12, "uuid" => 11],
];
$result = [];
foreach ($items as $i) {
    array_key_exists($i["did"], $result) ? $result[$i["did"]][] = $i["uuid"] : $result[$i["did"]] = [$i["uuid"]];
}
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 11
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 11
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
        )

)
```

[Php demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd225f3bfe5162e7dee1d549c4896ed46b2e3178)